# SQL Pick random value from enum type

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm running in postgresql and i want to choose a random value from a simple enum type. I could not find a way online tho.

This is a type example:

```
create type letter as enum('A','B','C','D');
```

now i just want to randomly choose one of the letters.
thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a few ways of going about this. I would use `enum_range` to dump the enum values and then `unnest` to split them into their own rows, then just randomly grab one of the records:

```
SELECT myletter FROM ( SELECT unnest(enum_range(NULL::letter)) as myletter ) sub ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1;
```

I would imagine you could probably do this in a single select without the nesting using some different functions, but this is pretty clear, logically, for the next person that has to decipher what you were doing.

---

From @pozs in the comments here, apparently the subselect is superfluous since Postgres supports sticking the `unnest()` directly in the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT myletter FROM unnest(enum_range(NULL::letter)) myletter ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: The sub-select is unnecessary though, `FROM unnest(...) myletter` is completely valid in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Oh very nice. I only dabble in postgres and I'm always delighted with it's clean syntax and it's nice little shortcuts like this.

Comment: oh great, this also returns as a 'letter' type. works as planned thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I'd join pg_type and pg_enum for it:

```
select e.* 
from pg_type t 
join pg_enum e on e.enumtypid = t.oid where typname='letter' 
order by random() 
limit 1;
```

Eg:

```
t=# select enumlabel from pg_type t join pg_enum e on e.enumtypid = t.oid where typname='letter' order by random() limit 1;
 enumlabel
-----------
 A
(1 row)

t=# select enumlabel from pg_type t join pg_enum e on e.enumtypid = t.oid where typname='letter' order by random() limit 1;
 enumlabel
-----------
 D
(1 row)

t=# select enumlabel from pg_type t join pg_enum e on e.enumtypid = t.oid where typname='letter' order by random() limit 1;
 enumlabel
-----------
 B
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot works like a charm. _especially 'select e.enumlabel' gives back  just the letter_ . I will have to find out how this piece of code works tho cause it seems a bit unfamiliar.